# How to hide specific drives on a server?

Tags: group-policy, remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, remote-access, user-management

I would like to know what's the recommended solution for the following problem.

We do not want users to see (or at least not to modify) the drives D and E of a server they have remote access to.

However, the tools installed on that server still need to have access to those drives in order to be able to work properly.

Comment: There's a Group Policy setting you can enable to hide those drives from users. The setting does not prevent programmatic access to those drives.

Comment: Do you know which one? Does it also work for drive E?

Comment: https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#2650

Comment: Found that one, too. However, it does not allow hiding of drive E.

Comment: Right. There's a setting to restrict/hide access to all drives. That's the one you should use. It will prevent users from viewing and accessing all local drives in Windows/File Explorer, etc. It does not prevent programmatic access to those drives for SQL, Exchange, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, they need to have access to some of the drives.This is what makes it difficult.

Comment: What about ACLs? Allow the users to read/write to the places they need to have access to and prevent access to everything else....

Comment: I think it can only be done by this [hack](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/231289/using-group-policy-objects-to-hide-specified-drives) proposed by Microsoft but on the same site they are saying _Microsoft does not recommend to change the System.adm file, but instead to create a new .adm file and import this .adm into the GPO. The reason is that if you apply changes to the system.adm file, these changes might get overwritten if Microsoft releases a new version of the system.adm file in a Service Pack._ Anyway, how can a OS missing native support for such a basic feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This registry setting helped us to hide the drive letters:
https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-nodrives.html